# Google Charts with prototype.js

Tags: prototypejs, google-visualization

I'm trying to use google geochart on my website. But the problem is when draw geochart, I receive error: "Object # has no method 'each'"

Here the code I'm trying:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Popularity'],
            ['Germany', 200],
            ['United States', 300],
            ['Brazil', 400],
            ['Canada', 500],
            ['France', 600],
            ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
</script>

<div id="chart_1">Chart should be here</div>
```

Everything works fine when I remove prototype.js from the page, but I have to leave it. 
Any suggestions how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Your code works here both with or without prototype. You should set some width/height on the container, though.

Answer (score 5):

Look at https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#prototype

and try to include `1.7.1.0`, `1.7.0.0`, `1.6.1.0`, `1.6.0.3` or `1.6.0.2`

You will get the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'each'` for any version prior to 1.7.1.0, so you just have to update your prototype with latest version available.

Some explanation would here be required, but I really cant tell exactly why. According to the [1.7.1 announcement](http://prototypejs.org/2012/08/08/prototype-1-7-1/) the dom.js has been totally rewritten. An update from 1.7 to 1.7.1 which took *18 months* (!!) The 1.7.0 RC3 is as far back as oct 2010, "including support for IE9" (!!) - so I guess a lot of programming regarding "new" HTML5 tags especially as the `<svg>`-tag google visualization uses a lot, is the reason behind it was not working prior to 1.7.1.